# How to make the app redirect me to login if there is no user

Tags: reactjs

why doesn't this work? And it doesn't redirect me to login if there is no user?

```
          {user ?
            <>
              <Route path="/" exact element={<HomePage />} />
              <Route path="*" exact element={<ErrorPage />} />
              <Route path="/moviedetail" exact element={<MovieDetails />} />
              <Route path="/categories" exact element={<Categories />} />
            </> :
            <Navigate to="/login" />
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

This don't work because you put `<Navigate to="/login" />` inside `BrowserRouter` component, just move it outside, try this below:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  ...
  <Route path="/" exact element={<HomePage />} />
  <Route path="*" exact element={<ErrorPage />} />
  <Route path="/moviedetail" exact element={<MovieDetails />} />
  <Route path="/categories" exact element={<Categories />} />
  ...
<BrowserRouter />
{!user && <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />}
```